# PostgreSQL instance encryption problems

Tags: database, postgresql, encryption

I am trying to encrypt "at rest" a postgresql database (on WINDOWS) and I have followed the steps from this source:
https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/attachment/62301/README.encryption

But when I want to create the encrypted instance using the command:
`initdb -K /data/my_pwd_command.sh -D data_encrypted`
it says that the option -K illegal. So, I can not pass the encryption key... Could anyone explain why I do not have this option? Or could suggest me another way to encrypt the DB at rest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's just the attachment of a post to a PostgreSQL mailing list, it is *not* the documentation and does *not* describe an existing feature.

PostgreSQL doesn't support that. There are proprietary solutions (although probably not on Windows), but my recommendation is to simply use an encrypted file system to store the database. Then you have the same effect with less trouble.

Let me add that encrypting database files adds very little security for a high performance price.

Comment: I saw that VeraCrypt and TrueCrypt works both on linux and windows and I can use them from command line. If you have other better suggestions for file system encryption please tell me. Thanks

Comment: I have never used fil system encryption myself, so I cannot make recommendations.